# app.json configuration for ssl kraken-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, configuration, kraken.js

Helle everyone ! i'm new to kraken-js and i'm trying to run an https server with kraken-js

The code i'm using come from this example:
https://github.com/lmarkus/Kraken_Example_Passport

I'm trying to configure the app.json but the server log an error:
PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no sart line

Here is m'y app.json file:

```
{
    "databaseConfig": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "database": "thisisNoPass"
    },

    "bcrypt": {
        "difficulty": 8
    },
"ssl" : {
            "pfx" : "",
            "key" : "MIICXQIBAAKBgQDkHi61iwlupemIlrPr1pm4VvRUl0pVsOVrDz5molvv52+w2/7p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",
            "passphrase" : "thisisNoPass",
            "cert" : "MIIB9TCCAV4CCQDfXU6l39aVSTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA/MQswCQYDVQQGEwJm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",
    "ca" : [ "" ],
    "crl" : [ "" ]
        },

    "port" : 80
}
```

I don't know what i've to put in the pfx field (path to the file ?), files were created with this tutorial:
http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html

Comment: Why a PFX file? Usually you don't mix PKCS12 files with PEM-encoded certs and keys. Is there something telling you you need a pfx?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the path handlers provided by shortstop. This means you don't have to include the entire cert in the config:

Also, don't mix your ssl strategies up:

If you're using a signed certificate:

```
   "ssl":{
       "cert":"file://path/to/server.crt",
       "key":"file://path/to/privkey.pem"
   }
```

If you're using a pfx/passphrase combo:

```
   "ssl":{
       "pfx":"file://path/to/certificateFile.pfx",
       "passphrase":"bananas"
   }
```